# SwiftUI Json декодирование (не возможное имя переменной)

Tags: json, swift, api, swiftui

Приведу как можно короче пример, есть запрос по api, с возращением json формата, проблема заключается в том что несколько заголовков json имеют такую структуру -> "opensearch:totalResults": "4310", А для декодирования требуется создать структуру ровно с таким же именем, но в имени не могут находится спец символы.

Пример кода с получение и декодированием ниже:

Структура:

```
import Foundation

struct NewMusic : Decodable {
    var name : String
    var artist : String
}
```

Метод декодирование:

```
func getMusic() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "Ссылка на API") else {return print("ERROR")}

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Request error: ", error)
                return
            }

            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }

            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                print("DATA = \(data)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    do {
                        let decodedMusic = try JSONDecoder().decode(Music.self, from: data)
                        self.mus = decodedMusic //mus место хранения
                    } catch let error {
                        print("Error decoding: ", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

Json результат:

```
{
    "#name": "Believer",
    "#artist": "Imagine Dragons"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в вашу структуру `CodingKeys`, это должно помочь, когда название приходящих полей не совпадает с code-convention в Swift'е или впринципе не может использоваться в языке Swift:

```
struct NewMusic: Codable {
    var name : String
    var artist : String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "#name"
        case artist = "#artist"
    }
}
```